# Show unparsed PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to show unparsed PHP code in my HTML.
For example, I want this to render in my HTML documents.

> This is how you print text in PHP
>
> ```
> <?php print "Hello!"; ?>
> ```

Comment: if your going to teach others, learn a little yourself first ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By printing the codes as a string with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), they will not be parsed by either your server or the browser.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<?php print "Hello!"; ?>')
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`highlight_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) function in PHP.

You pass in a file and it either prints out the source with syntax highlighting to screen or with an optional `return` parameter, you can echo it out where you want. Example: `highlight_file($file)` or `echo highlight_file($file,true)`

There are examples in the link to also get line numbers for the code.

Other methods require manually reading the file with other functions in PHP and/or require having the source code you want as strings in other files.

Using `highlight_file` is really good as you can have a working PHP file somewhere so a person can see what it does and very easily view the source with highlighting. This would be the best method for showing code as a tutorial or reference.

**EDIT**

You can also do highlighting of a value that is stored in a string with [`highlight_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, use "&lt;" and "&gt;" for your '<' and '>' characters.

```
<p>This is how you print text in PHP</p>
&lt;?php print "Hello!"; ?&gt;
```